# how to include pivot data at same level as other data in eloquent

Tags: many-to-many, eloquent-relationship

I have lots of many-to-many relationships in my code, and the pivot tables typically include a user-controlled nickname and a soft delete column as well. eg:

```
'user' table:
- id
- name
- email

'category' table:
- id
- description

'category_user' table:
- id
- user_id
- category_id
- name
- deleted_at
```

The relationship is defined as:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'usercat', 'uc_user', 'uc_cat')
        ->where('uc_del', 0)
        ->withPivot(['uc_name', 'uc_del']);
}
```

When I run a typical Eloquent query on this data it will return something like:

```
all: [
  App\Models\Category {#6462
    id: 1,
    description: 'Groceries and restaurants etc'
    pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#6463
      user_id: 1,
      category_id: 1,
      name: "Food",
      deleted_at: 0,
    },
  },
}
```

I've been creating a separate array and manually pulling all the data into a single level. eg:

```
foreach($result->get() as $key => $category) {
    array_push($categories, [
        'id' => $categories['id'],
        'name' => $categories['pivot']['name'],
        'description' => $categories['description'],
        'deleted' => $categories['pivot']['deleted_at']
    ]);
}
```

It seems there should be a better way to do this if Eloquent were to live up to its name. Please tell me I'm missing something.